# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/bidi/HasBiDi on the latest Selenium 4.11.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide

First time faced once I did an update to Selenide v6.17.0

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

(which uses Selenium v4.11.0 as an internal dependency).

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

And got an error from start:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/bidi/HasBiDi

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    .....
```

Code breaks on the line which has to open URL

```
open("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

I believe it's completely on the selenium side, cause I performed a few experiments (added separate dependency to my pom for Selenium v4.11.0 itself) and it leads to mentioned error even with earlier versions of selenide.

So it's enough to just reduce selenide version to lower than `6.17` or selenium to lower than `4.11` to stop experiencing this problem according to what I managed to found out.

Please share your experience with solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to have in your pom Selenium Remote Driver with corresponding version to fix this error.
In my case helped just to add the following to my pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```